# How do you create model objects in a Django view?

Tags: python, django

I know how to create model objects via a submitted form, but I'm wondering how to create objects in a view without having to go through a form. I'm aware that this can be done via the shell, but I have different reasons for doing it in the view.

As an example let's say I have a blog table that has a title and a body. How would I create a new object that sets the fields of the title and body?

```
def create_blog(request):
    # Create a new blog object.
    blog_obj.title= "First Blog"
    blog_obj.body= "This is the body"
```

Update:
Here is my model.py

```
from django.db import models 

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_ratings = models.IntegerField()
    total_rating_value = models.IntegerField()
    rating_average = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
```

Update 2:
when I try saving my object it returns an error (class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'). rating_average is a Decimal_field.
This is my actual object:

```
rating_obj = Rating(movie_name="Test Movie", total_ratings=1, total_rating_value= 5, rating_average= 5.0)
```

Comment: Same way you normally create objects in Python.

Comment: Also you can access any parameter in `request.POST[param]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is straight forward Python code and nothing specific to Django:

```
blog_obj = Blog(title="First Blog", body="This is the body")
```

Maybe you want to go through the good and easy to understand [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api)?

**EDIT:**
In order to solve your problem with your `DecimalField` you need to set `max_digits` greater than `decimal_places`.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield):

> Note that this number must be greater than or equal to decimal_places.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I try saving my object it returns an error (class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'). My rating_average is a Decimal_field. This is my actual object: rating_obj = Rating(movie_name="Test Movie", total_ratings=1, total_rating_value= 5, rating_average= 5.0)

Comment: We need to see your model definition. Please edit and improve your question as a DecimalField has several options, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I totally overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a model manager is recommended. Example from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/):

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        book = self.create(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")
```